# Compile React from Gulp "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp

I have an existing project that is built with gulp and I am trying to add a simple 'Hello World' React app to it.  Running `gulp` produces no errors in the terminal, but in the browser console I have the error:

```
"Uncaught Error: Module parse failed:
/private/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/app/back/js/index.jsx Unexpected token (7:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.".
```

The folder structure is:

```
public_html/
  app/
    back/
      js/
        index.jsx
        bundle.js     #this should get created by the transpile
  .babelrc
  .gulpfile
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
```

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var Test = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( <Test /> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json:

```
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.10",
    "gulp-header": "^1.8.7",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.10",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
...
var webpack = require('webpack')
var webpack_config = require('./webpack.config.js');
...
gulp.task('webpack', [] ,(done) => {
   webpack(webpack_config, function(err, stats) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('error');
        }
        else {
            console.log('no error');
        }
        done();
    });
});
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var config = {
   entry: './app/back/js/index.jsx',
   output: {
      path: './dist/app/back/js',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module : {
      loaders : [
         {
            test : /\.jsx?/,
            include : './app/back/js',
            loader : 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['es2015']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
};

module.exports = config;
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015"]
}
```

I have tried multiple solutions from SO but the error persists.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What version of webpack are you using?

Comment: `npm view webpack version` tells me 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by following Tom's instructions for `package.json` and `.babelrc` **but also** needed to use this `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var config = {
   entry: './app/back/js/index.jsx',
   output: {
      path: __dirname + '/app/back/js',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module : {
      loaders : [
         {
            test : /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader : 'babel-loader'
         }
      ]
   }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will are missing this babel preset: `babel-preset-react`.

So 
package.json:

```
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.10",
    "gulp-header": "^1.8.7",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.10",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

And there is some small misconfiguration inside `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var config = {
   entry: './app/back/js/index.jsx',
   output: {
      path: './dist/app/back/js',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module : {
      loaders : [
         {
            test : /\.jsx?$/,
            include : './app/back/js',
            loader : 'babel-loader'
         }
      ]
   }
};

module.exports = config;
```